# 大人であれ\であろうと 子供であれ\であろうと

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I'm a little confused about some Japanese forms which seem rather similar to me and I'd like to understand the difference between them.

> 大人であれ\であろうと 子供であれ\であろうと 、 信号を無視してはいけない。it doesn't matter if it is an adult or a child, the signal must not be ignored.

This seems similar to the following sentences in meaning and usage:

> - 世田谷学校の生徒であろうが生徒じゃなかろうが、この授業を受けることができる。
> - 犬だろうが猫だろうが、母はペットを飼うことを許してくれない。
> - 合格の見込みがあろうがあるまいが、今はただ頑張るだけだ。
> - 私達は、持ちつ持たれつの関係だ。

Comment: Yes, and there's no particular difference.

Comment: The last one seems to be an odd one out.

Answer (score 1):

I feel a little different nuance.

Aであれ\であろうと\だろうが、 Bであれ\であろうと\だろうが means "even if it would be A or B" and it would be close to "whatever it would be".

Aであろうがあるまいが\Aであろうがなかろうが means "whether A or not".

持ちつ持たれつ is an idiom which means "give‐and‐take".

Comment: "持ちつ持たれつ" describes interdependent relationships while "give-and-take" is more about making concessions to reach an agreement, I think.